# Laravel application on Nginx with Docker keeps redirecting to the initial page

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm learning **Docker** and my goal is to set up a **Laravel application running on Nginx**.

I managed to get to the initial login page, but when I enter credentials and try to login it redirects to the same initial page.

My guess is that is something wrong with the Nginx `default.conf` file. I tried a lot of things, it must be something simple that I'm missing, it's really frustrating.

Below are some info related to my problem. If there's any other info that I should provide, please let me know.

#### My folder structure is organized like this:

*(It doesn't show all the files inside the `src` folder, but that's where I cloned the Laravel application)*

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── nginx/
│   └── default.conf
└── src/
    ├── app/
    ├── bootstrap/
    ├── config/
    ├── database/
    ├── public/
    ...
    ├── .env
    ├── composer.json
    ...
```

#### Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "8088:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "4306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: temp
      MYSQL_USER: temp
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:13.7
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

#### Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

#### And here's the default.conf file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

---

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this?

Comment: Still waiting on an answer to this question. Facing the same issue. On my end I have to always put the application down and up again for it to work. But it gets fraustrating if you have more than one application

Comment: Same problem in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly what the Issue is, but from my limited view. Check the loginController.php for what the $redirectTo is set equal to. That needs to point to the page you want to go to after login. If you can provide more information that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Alex. The request doesn't even arrive at the loginController.php. This same Laravel application works outside docker on Apache.

Comment: what is in your config file on the nginx server /sites-available/YOUR-SITE?